# Нахождение горизонтальных и вертикальных прямых в изображении

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("risunok.png",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

print(img.shape)
cv2.imshow("original",img)
im()
intIMAGE= cv2.integral(img)
MaxFormatValue = 255
koeff=MaxFormatValue/intIMAGE[intIMAGE.shape[0]-1][intIMAGE.shape[1]-1]

integral=intIMAGE*(koeff)
npINTEG=np.asarray(integral)

print("Viberite oblast izobrazheniya:")
x=int(input()) #0
y=int(input()) #610
diff_image=cv2.Sobel(npINTEG[x:,:y],-1,1,1)

plt.plot(diff_image)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(diff_image)
plt.show()

cv2.imshow("part of image",img[x:,:y])


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

По заданию требовалось сделать полутоновое интегральное изображение, а потом использовать **свойства интегрального изображения** для того, чтобы найти прямые. Как мне тут ранее сказали, нужно использовать производную для нахождения этих прямых. Я использовал Собеля для нахождения этих прямых. Но в итоге, построив график, я не получил доходчивого результата. Как мне реализовать программу, чтобы наглядно продемонстрировать наличие горизонтальных и вертикальных линий на изображении ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Вроде вышло]

Я попробовал через Лапласа, а не Собеля, похоже на правду

Comment: Код лучше добавить текстом, тогда ответ будет более полезен.